# SceneView and Scene isPlaying, isPaused

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

What is the difference between using `scene.isPaused` and `sceneView.isPlaying`? Are these just the same things approached from different place? Is changing one to true, changes other to false and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, this is where I landed so your actual mileage may vary :)

If isPlaying (SCNRenderer) is set to false (default), the scene time does not increment, therefore animations associated with the scene do not play (from Apple Docs).  Even though the example game code doesn't make this call and it still animates, you'll likely want this turned on IF you plan to process some logic in the render loop and you want to render loop to be called even if no animation is occurring.

if isPaused is set to true (also from docs), animations and physics engines will stop.  You can also pause an individual node (I haven't tried it though).

So and IMO - although they seem to be related, it's really two different things.  Your animations could be paused, but you may still want to force the render loop to run in order to process other logic.  Please keep in mind that you are potentially impacting FPS if you are processing logic within the render loop.

Hope that helps.